# Java- Extract part of a string between two similar special characters

Tags: java

Java- Extract part of a string between two similar special characters.

I want to `substring` the second number, example :

```
String str = '1-10-251';
```

I want the result to be: `10`

Comment: Read up on the `split` method of the `String` class.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract a substring from a string in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1265119/how-to-extract-a-substring-from-a-string-in-java)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java- Extract part of a string between two special characters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4962176/java-extract-part-of-a-string-between-two-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

```
String str = "1-10-251";
String[] strArray = str.split("-");
System.out.println(strArray[1]);
```

Comment: Maybe consider to add some text to the code, to help future readers to learn even more from your answer :-)